# Do you always need to one-hot encode if you have classification task

Tags: tensorflow, classification, mnist, one-hot-encoding

I’m really new in deep learning and I came across with MNIST dataset problem.

So my question is when you have a classification task are you supposed to do one hot encoding before feeding it to neural network?

Comment: *Do you always need to one-hot encode if you have classification task?* No. Check [sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have a number of options based on the loss you select in  compiling your model. Typical you set the loss in model.compile to categorical_cross_entropy if you have one hot encoded your labels. However you can encode your labels as integers and use sparse_categorical_crossentropy as you loss function.